# Going from Abstract to a usable Integer?

Tags: c#, delegates, abstract-class

I was trying to follow an example in a book and then wanted to put values in by pressing a button.  This has to be a simple fix, just trying to figure out the basics.

```
 abstract class Spaceship
{
    abstract public void LaserHit();
}
class CombatShip : Spaceship
{
    public override void LaserHit(int L)
    {
       int L = 10;
    }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CombatShip goliath = new CombatShip();
        int L = goliath.LaserHit() - 10;


    }
}
```

Comment: Your LaserHit method is expecting an integer. Do you mean to do `int L = goliath.LaserHit(10)`? The method also doesn't do anything with the parameter it's expecting.

Comment: What exactly you're trying to perform in the code? Currently it is totally unclear due to the wrong usage of the method call.

Comment: Not only wrong usage but I dare say this code does not compile at all. The override LaserHit method has a different signature than the abstract method. In button_Click the method is used as if it returned a value (int?) but both method definition and declaration have void return value. SDJ, you need to state your problem a lot clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to method signature of your `LaserHit` method. Return type is `void` -> meaning this method will not return anything. You're trying to assign value returned by `LaserHit` , but it is designed not to return anything.

Change method signature both in abstract class and in concrete class to int and you'll get what you want.

```
abstract class Spaceship
{
    abstract public int LaserHit();
}
class CombatShip : Spaceship
{
    public override int LaserHit()
    {
       int L = 10;
       return L;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay attention too, your code wont compile :)

Comment: Thanks, edited signature of LaserHit in abstract class

Comment: Pay attention once again:)

Comment: So my biggest problem when I was coding this was the Int and the void.... How would you use a void and pull something through without a return?